# API enabling in trial version

Tags: api

I have recently signed for a trial version of Salesforce (my.salesforce.com). I tried to Generate Enterprise WSDL, but get an error Insufficient Privileges.

Also how do I verify if the account has API enabled (for integrations from other app)

Comment: You should be able to download the WSDL as long as you have permission, even if you don't have API access. Are you sure you're logged in as a System Administrator? You can check by typing your name in the global search bar, clicking on your name, then clicking on the User Detail button, and checking the "User Profile" field found on the right-hand side near the top.

Comment: Hi, yes System Administrator profile.  Profile System Administrator

Answer (score 0):

I was able to replicate the error in my trail org. The trail org created defaults to Professional Edition.As per https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000326486&type=1&mode=1, Professional Edition is listed as an edition without API access.

> For Professional Edition organizations, all requests for API access must be purchased and can be processed by contacting your Account Executive.

The "API Enabled" Checkbox would not be visible in the professional edition which is usually available in supported editions by default (Path: Setup> profiles>System Administrator>Administrative Permissions)

Comment: @user6816447 Are you able to verify the above details in your org. Happy to answer any follow-up queries. Thanks